# Intercept garbage collection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, es6-proxy

Proxies have a delete trap, deleteProperty, but I'm curious if there's any way to generally intercept garbage collection on any object?

So something that could handle the following:

```
o = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
delete o.a // if o is a proxy, I could use the deleteProperty trap

a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
a.pop() // I presume same thing?

f = function(){ let x = 0; };
f = null; // x is lost to garbage collection(?)
```

I'm trying to know when an object or primitive is garbage collected so that I can do a check on something.

Comment: Define *"check on something"* in meaningful terms and as a higher level objective

Comment: No, proxies don't solve this. I recommend to read http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ https://v8.dev/features/weak-references https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs